# Get Data from Same Api with different params in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am calling one api by using axios.

Below is my code for api call with **axios.get**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ExpireAlertRestart } from "../components/common-components/api-expire-alert";
import { getMessagesAPIResponse } from "../store/actions/home-screen-all-actions";

const GetMessagesAPI = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [currentSpinnerState, setCurrentSpinnerState] = useState(true);
  //NOTE: retrieving loginAuthToken from store
  const loginAuthToken = useSelector(
    (state) => state.loginAuthTokenReducer.loginAuthToken
  );
  //NOTE:taking oved input and company selection code for dynamic parameter
  const companyValue = useSelector(
    (state) => state.changeCompanyReducer.company
  );
  const companyCode = companyValue[0];
  const employeeId = companyValue[1];
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://mobileapi.unq.co.il/GetMessages", {
        params: {
          company: companyCode,
          year1: "2020",
          month1: "9",
          employee: employeeId,
          DisplayRow: "5",
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${loginAuthToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((data) => dispatch(getMessagesAPIResponse(data)))
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          //NOTE: handling token expire
          return ExpireAlertRestart();
        } else {
          Alert.alert(error.message);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setCurrentSpinnerState(false));
  }, []);

  return {
    currentSpinnerState: currentSpinnerState,
  };
};

export default GetMessagesAPI;
```

i want to get the data from same api with different params.

lets say for second time i want to give the params like

```
 params: {
          company: companyCode,
          year1: "2019",
          month1: "8",
          employee: employeeId,
          DisplayRow: "5",
        },
```

i want to get two different params data from same api.

How can i get data from same api with different **year1** and **month1** value?

Comment: POST call is ideal for this kind of requests

Comment: define your axios.get code inside a function (eg: `get_messages`) that receives params as parameter, that way u can reuse it with differemtn params `get_messages({year1: "2019"})` and `get_messages({year1: "2021"})`

Comment: can you write code for this solution @psiro hyarte_7